# Three semicircles on top os screen Android pie?

Tags: stock-android

Everytime i open my menu on my asus zenfone max m2 stock android these three semicircles appear on the top at random does anyone has a clue what are these?[image: look at top this always appears when i open the menu in pie have a look]

Comment: Looks like overlay from some app. You should check the apps for which you have granted the "Draw over other apps" permission.

Comment: Just figured it out pal t'was actually a bug in my phone these are icons of the dock which appear at the top

Comment: @TheGalagaGuy looks like you found the solution to your question by yourself, which is great! Feel free to post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed but also encouraged!](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).